# How to make active a window without a title bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, window, makekeyandordertofront

I can send the message makeKeyAndOrderFront: to make a window active. However, if I send this to a window without a title bar, it doesnt make it active. Is there any way to make a window without a title bar active?

Comment: What do you mean by “doesnt make it active”? Also, did you add anything special to your Info.plist?

Comment: actually i suspect a window without a title bar cant be made active. cos the normal behavior of a window when clicked is to be active, that is the UI controls change color in an obvious way, but i cant ever make it active when i click on this titlebar-less window. Nope nothing special added to info.plist.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the case, particularly since some custom-title-bar windows are done as borderless windows. I'd encourage you to keep poking the methods of NSWindow and NSPanel until you find the right combination of settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override [`-canBecomeKeyWindow`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCICBFJF) in your `NSWindow` subclass to return `YES`.

As per the docs:

> Attempts to make the window the key window are abandoned if this
>   method returns NO. The NSWindow implementation returns YES if the
>   window has a title bar or a resize bar, or NO otherwise.